# Output without "print()" in SublimeText

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Is there a way/plug-in to enable output without "print()" in SublimeText?

For example,

```
a = 1 + 2
print (a)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Wanted:

```
a = 1 + 2
a
```

Output:

```
3
```

P.s. I also tried below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use `$ python` in the integrated terminal?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan, thank you for your comment. Can you please help me more with "use $ python in the integrated terminal"? I tried added a line "# $ python", then run the lines, it doesn't work. thanks.

Comment: just type `python` in the terminal. then enter in your code. then using `a` will return a's value

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan, thanks again. I tried it. The try screenshot was pasted on the question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: He means not in a `.py` file... directly inside your terminal not in a file run the command `python`  it will open up a repl which is likely what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the answer is no. You can rename the print function to make it less noticable like this:

```
_ = print

a = 2

_(a)
```

Output is `2`

Alternatively:

As a few people mentioned in the comments, what you are likely looking for is a `repl`, which you can get by simply running `python` command directly in your terminal.

like this:

```
$ python
```

that should take you to an interactive environment that gives you real time results for the python code you input. Below is an example...

```
>>> a = 1 + 2
>>> a
3
>>> a + 25
28
>>> a
3
>>> a = a + 25
>>> a
28
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I do mean in a .py file. Uploaded a screenshot using "$ python", can you please have a look?

Comment: @MarkK  Then sorry to say but the answer is no.  there is no way to just output a variable or value without calling some sort of print function.  That's just how the interpreter works.  You can rename the print function to something more discrete but that's all I can think of

Comment: @MarkK that's just not how .py files work. Even if there is a way to do it, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @Markk I updated my answer. Sorry I wish I could help

Comment: @alexpdev, always grateful to sharing of knowledge! :)

Comment: Note that the `$` in `$ python` indicates that it is a terminal command. And you don't actually include the `$` in the command. So all you type in the terminal is `python`